# Case default owner is overriding specified case owner

Tags: case, assignment-rules, ownership

We have third party form builder tool called Wufoo that creates records on a custom object when a form is submitted. If certain criteria applies, we trigger a case creation and specify who the case owner is.

However, after the Case is created and assigned. Salesforce will auto-assign the Case to the "Default Owner" found in Build > Customize > Cases> Support Settings.

As you can see below the correct owner is assigned, but Salesforce will reassign the record:
[image]

To try debugging the issue, I created a case manually and Salesforce will not override the owner.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can assign my Case a new owner without Default Owner overriding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating cases from a trigger, you can specify [DMLOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm) to prevent the assignment rules from firing. Something like this:

```
trigger X on Y (after insert) {
    Case[] cases = new Case[0];
    for(Y record: Trigger.new) {
         if(someCondition) {
             cases.add(new Case(...));
         }
    }
    Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
    options.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
    cases.setOptions(options);
    insert cases;
}
```

I haven't personally used DMLOptions before, so you may need to tweak this answer a bit.

Comment: note also that DmlOptions can also be set by an API client if Cases are being created by the WuFoo system

Comment: @crop1645 True, except this question specifically says they are creating the records via triggers, so this is the answer I provided. It is true that WuFoo could control this if they were creating cases directly, which appears to lot be the case.

Comment: sorry, I guess I more broadly interpreted OP's: 'we trigger' as not necessarily meaning 'we invoke a trigger'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried this and get the following error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [LIST<Case>].setOptions(Database.DMLOptions) (Line: 51, Column: 9)`. To elaborate, this code is written in a Trigger.

Comment: Figured out that I could add the option to individual Case record instead of the LIST<Case>. Looks like it is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox I am creating cases in an APEX function and this also received a boolean to allow default rules to run or not.  Now in the same function while adding a new or existing case to upsert in the end, I am setting options to each with the flag value but this is not honored and always the rules run even when the flag is false. Could you tell me if I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: code for the above question is followingList<Case> cases; // Contains new and existing cases 
//This will be set from the UI based on whether the auto assignment of case should happen or not
Boolean useDefaultRule; 

Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();

options.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = useDefaultRule;

List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();

for(Case case : cases){
   case.setOptions(options);
   caseList.add(case);
}
upsert caseList;

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Write a Case assignment rule that executes first - criteria = if case originated from WuFoo.
2. Assign to any active user
3. Check the box 'do not reassign owner'

see for example - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008zGWIAY

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently; and this is how it works for me:

- Leave the default owner in the support setting.
- Create an assignement rule that affect your cases to another specific user,unlike the default one (for example a system admin)
- Fire your trigger CaseBeforeUpdate,with a criteria  based on the last owner which is the one assigned by the assignement rule.

Answer (score -1):

Sforce-Auto-Assign: FALSE
add it in header while making a call to salesforce.
[Please refer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm)